Magento 2 error trying to get children information
I am trying to get children product information from Magento 2 API REST and it returns  an error when the product sku has special characters or simbols.
SKU: "Risk + Box"
I tried the following requests and the api returns error everytime.
"[base_url]/rest/V1/configurable-products/Risk+%2B+Box/children"
"[base_url]/rest/V1/configurable-products/Risk + Box/children"
"[base_url]/rest/V1/configurable-products/Risk%20+%20Box/children"

Error:
The nonce is already being used by the consumer with ID %1","parameters":["10"]
I know the error message is not related to the product, but it only occurs when the sku has special characters.
